# How to create a citation/quote from a Postgres text field?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a database with a lot of text and I want to find the surrounding text for a word that I am searching for i.e. If I search this text for "text" I should get something like (and more consistent than):

- .. lot of text and ..
- .. the surrounding text for ..
- .. this text for "text"..
- .. for "text" I should ..

I can write this in a program but I wondered if there is a good SQL trick to get something approaching this with just a query for a quick and dirty report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is the ts_headline function. it does exactly what you need it seems. here is the documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch-controls.html